# Behaviour of Javascript array objects

Tags: javascript

```
function map(f, a) {
  for(var i in a) {
    a[i] = f(a[i]);
  }
}

var a = [0, 1, 2, 3];
map(function(x) { return x = x * x }, a);
console.log(a);
```

a: `[0, 1, 4, 9]`

However, If I change `map(f, a)` to:

```
function map(f, a) {
  for(var i in a) {
    f(a[i]);
  }
}
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3];
map(function(x) { return x = x * x }, a);
console.log(a);
```

a remains unchanged as: `[0, 1, 2, 3]`

I'm not sure what's happening here. It appears as if the interpreter considers `a[i]` as a reference to a property of the object `a` in `map(f, a)` but once passed into `f` it turns into a `typeof number`.

Comment: I expect a to change in the second example.

Comment: That would require pretty extreme call-by-reference - which doesn't exist in JS (just try `var x = 0; function f(x) { x = 1 }; f(x)`). You are throwing the result of `f(a[i])` away!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `for(... in...)` on Arrays. Use a `for loop`.

Enumeration order with `for in` is **NOT** guaranteed. It will also iterate over properties (not the built ins but stuff that were set by JS code) and stuff on the prototype, and then all hell breaks loose.

Next thing, all values except for arrays and objects are **pass by value** (basically arrays and objects are also pass by value, but the value is a pointer to the object).

So you're not modifying the value inside the array in this case, but the local variable `x` which just happens to have them same value.

`return x = x * x` the assignment is superfluous.

**Fixed version**

```
function map(f, a) {
  for(var i = 0, l = a.length; i < l; i++) {
    a[i] = f(a[i]);
  }
}

var a = [0, 1, 2, 3];
map(function(x) { return x * x }, a);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Array.prototype.foo = 2; for(var i in [])console.log(i) > 'foo' - Updated my wording to state it more clear, everything that's enumerable will get listed.

Comment: I have no means of testing now but I'll take your word for it.

Comment: I used `for in` since I didn't modify `a` in any way.

Comment: @Sahil Your code will break as soon as someone else modifies Array.prototype, infamous example being the widely used Prototype.js library. Always use a for loop for arrays. It's more secure, and a thousand times faster too.

Comment: A thousand times faster? Really?

Comment: @TimDown It is a hell lot slower http://jsperf.com/for-in-vs-for-loop) there's lot of overhead, enumeration of the keys, the call to hasOwnProperty etc.

Comment: That's a surprising difference, and makes me skeptical about the test. I get a much less dramatic difference (typically between a factor of 4 and 20 across browsers) in a simple test I've just knocked up, which just tests the loops themselves: http://jsfiddle.net/7XB7L/ . Btw, I entirely agree with you about everything you've said. It's just the scale of this performance difference that seems off.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct behavior, it's the *value* of `a[i]` is passed into `f([i])`, not the reference to it, so that `x` inside is a distinctly different variable/reference.

In the first version you're taking the result of that still different `x` (*returned* by the function) and assigning it to that array position afterwards...that's the only way to use that new *value* for something.

Answer (score 0):

This call:

```
a[i] = f(a[i]);
```

is actually similar to this:

```
var arg = a[i];
var res = f(arg);
a[i] = res;
```

This is called "call-by-value", see here:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_by_value

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in JavaScript are Objects, and Objects are always reference types.

Up to the point where `a` exists inside the map function you have been passing it as an entire array which means that changes you make to `a` will be visible externally.

Once you de-reference the array with `a[i]` you have a variable of type `Number` which is not a reference type. Therefore, changes to `x` in your anonymous function will not be propagated back to the array, and are only visible inside the anonymous function itself.

Comment: That's what I assumed. Thanks.